# How to use a lookup type for a static class member?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a Typescript class I defined a class member for a used type like this:

```
export class AccordionSection extends Component {
}

export class Accordion extends Component<AccordionProperties> {

    public static Section = AccordionSection;
}
```

I want to use this type in the AccordionProperties interface:

```
interface AccordionProperties {
    children?: Accordion["Section"];
}
```

Simply using `Accordion.Section` gives me the error

> 'Accordion' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

So I searched for a solution and found that lookup type approach. However, with this I get the error:

> Property 'Section' does not exist on type 'Accordion'.

What's the correct approach here to make this work with Typescript?

Answer (score 2):

The lookup approach is the right one. You then can lookup the [static side of a class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions) with `typeof Accordion`:

```
const AccordionSection = { a: "foo" }

export class Accordion {
  public static Section = AccordionSection;
}

interface AccordionProperties {
  children?: typeof Accordion["Section"]; // { a: string; } | undefined 
}
```

[Sample link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAgsUAnAJgS3AZQKbChsGAXhgG8YBDALhgCIAzEEWmAXwCh3sAPABxCSxgAGwoQI8RAPTgynGDF4BXAEbC0wGNAr5NOPAWKTkMsPvzgA3Ow7s0YKNiT0KwbMekEACkhC8n%20NgSpOwKwAAWaMIoSNhgAPw0UACe-iD0HqgEANq05gS0ALqWMAD0pWSUNNBI9gDmJawwAD4wSmAo2PT22CgwNkA)

Comment: The `typeof` keyword silences the transpiler, fine. However, it cannot be used then. Make the dummy Accordionsection a class and add this: `const test: typeof Accordion.Section = {  a: "bar" };` It gives the error that `a` does not exist in `typeof Accordion.Section`.

Comment: `typeof Accordion.Section` will infer whatever type you have for your static property `Section`. Given `AccordionSection` is a class, it would be the type of its constructor function, so you wouldn't be able to assign `{ a: "bar" }` to this type. Above example works for `public static Section = new AccordionSection();`. If that doesn't help, I suggest you extend the question with the concrete `AccordionSection` + the code provoking the error.

Comment: [Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=50&pln=4&pc=3#code/MYGwhgzhAECCzAPYCcAmBLRA7AygU2ABdMtoBvaMaAXmgCIAzRRO6AXwCgO8APABxSFooSDHhI0Jch2jQ+AVwBGIdMGgRCYYmvxEptLHgDucBCgzZdxbAAoAlAG4OnDuiyE8yBmGB5TEiywABWREPk9iPBgyGWEAC3QQVGQ8LAB+AC5oQgBPcMQGf3MSAG06KxI6AF0HaAB6OqLJSwJrUgAfaHksVDwGNzxUaGcuJCwNbKjCLNz8wvFi7AA6CuwackosukUwZFY2Jw4F5qwV1v1yMC2dvbYgA)

Comment: I added the declaration of `AccordionSection` to the code in my question, but it really makes no difference. Using `new AccordionSection()` creates an instance of that class, while I want in fact to alias `AccordionSection` with `Accordion.Section`, that's all. Additionally, I want to limit the possible `children` content to be an array of such sections. `AccordionSection[]` works there nicely, but as I wrote, I want to use the `Accordion.Section` syntax.

Comment: yeah, I already understood that. So you want to alias `AccordionSection` with `Accordion.Section`. Then static property `Section` contains the *class* itself (not instance). So you wouldn't be able to assign `{ a: "bar" }` to it. If you want to use the instance type of the class, use [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet), like `const test: InstanceType<typeof Accordion.Section> = { a: "bar" };`. Btw: is that React you are using?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's React.js. The InstanceType also is accepted but when I then use `<Accordion><Accordion.Section ...>...</Accordion.Section><Accordion>` it throws the error that `Element[]` misses certain properties (mostly functions from the class from which AccordionSection is derived). I should probably go a step back and approach this problem differently. Thanks anyway for your help attempt.